# 404 with .less on IIS7.5

Tags: less, iis-7.5

I saw this question [less on iis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606476/less-on-iis-not-working) but it does not seem to help. I am still doing something wrong, could someone give advice please?

In IIS7.5 I have done the follow for the server:
1) Installed dotless core in program files directory dotless core.

2) Added a "Native Module Registration" for the dotless core.
  Name "Dotless Core", path "C:\Program Files\dotless\dotless.Core.dll"

3) Added a handler
  Name "Dotless Core", modele "Dotless core" (above). (with and with executable)

4) MIME Type
  Extension ".less", MIME TYPE "text/css", Entry type "Local"

I have tried version of this and others but does not seem to change anything.

Sort of hoping there is an easier way of doing this?

Comment: LESS files should be compiled to CSS files during publishing. It is never a must to make them publicly available via IIS.

Comment: yea, that did the trick.  I was thinking since the files were minimized that was taken care of.  Thanks.

Comment: move it to an answer so that you can accept it and close the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the complexity of web standards and browser compatibility, it is a good practice to define a new standard such as LESS or SASS and then compile to old standard like CSS.

Thus, on your server side, the original files (.less and so on) can be hidden. Only compiled results (.css) are exposed.

This also applies to TypeScript (.ts) case.